# Compilar y ejecutar archivo Java sin IDE: Error, no se encuentra clase principal

Tags: java, cmd, compilar

En mi clase de programación nos pidieron hacer un programa simple y compilarlo, ejecutarlo y crear un .jar desde el CMD en windows (SIN IDE); cosa que aún no sé hacer, pues siempre usé Netbeans.

La ruta del archivo es:

> C:\JavaWorks\RFCJava\GetRFC.java

El archivo es el siguiente:

```
package getrfc;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class GetRFC {
    //contenido de la clase
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        pedirDatos();
    }
}
```

He hecho lo siguiente:

> C:> cd C:\JavaWorks\RFCJava
>
> C:\JavaWorks\RFCJava> javac GetRFC.java

Se me ha generado un archivo .class en el mismo directorio, lo normal. Al intentar ejecutar con "java", me sale:

> C:\JavaWorks\RFCJava> java GetRFC
>
> Error: no se ha encontrado o cargado la clase principal GetRFC

Pero la clase GetRFC.class está ahí mismo, por lo cual sí existe. Estamos iniciando en programación, así que quizá omití algo sencillo. Cualquier ayuda es bienvenida; ya que tampoco sé cómo hacer el .jar y hasta donde he investigado, necesito primero que el `java GetRFC` funcione.
Como nota adicional, el directorio sólo contiene el archivo .java y .class; nada más.

Comment: Hay una llave de `}` de más antes del _main_. , debe eliminarla y volver a ejecutar el `javac GetRFC.java`

Comment: @Dev.Joel eso no es todo. La clase está dentro de un paquete. Por ello, debes ubicarte fuera de la carpeta y compilar la clase desde allí.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considera que los paquetes son una estructura de carpetas que sirven para organizar tu código. Si tu clase comienza con la siguiente línea:

```
package getrfc;
```

Significa que tu archivo `.java` debe encontrarse dentro de una carpeta `getrfc`. Tu estructura de carpetas y archivos debería lucir así:

```
- C:/
  - algunaCarpetaParaTusProyectos/
    - getrfc
      + GetRFC.java
```

Luego, por línea de comandos (cmd en Windows), accedes a la carpeta donde se encuentre tu archivo. Ejemplo (el ingreso de comandos está denotado por `>`):

```
> cd C:\algunaCarpetaParaTusProyectos
> dir
  getrfc
> cd getrfc
> dir
  GetRFC.java
```

Luego, deberás compilar el archivo con `javac`. Para ejecutarlo, deberás subir por las carpetas hasta llegar **al mismo nivel de la raíz de los paquetes** y usar el nombre completo de la clase. El nombre completo es el nombre de la carpeta (o carpetas, dependiendo del paquete donde se encuentre) y el nombre del archivo:

```
# ya estamos dentro de C:\algunaCarpetaParaTusProyectos\getrfc
> javac GetRFC.java
# asumiendo que no hay errores de compilación
> cd ..
> java -cp . getrfc.GetRFC
# salida de tu programa Java
```